# which to use OLEDB or ODBC for SYbase

Tags: .net, database-connection, connection-string, sap-ase

I am not able to figure out which drivers should I use. Even I don't know what I have.

When I am trying to make the connection string through the .udl file it only shows SYbase ASE OleDB Provider

while in install folder I can see in driver list Syabse Ase ODBC driver but in connection string it is unable to pick up the driver, here I used Driver = (Sybase ASE ODBC Driver)

What should I go for?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Using udl you have only the possibility to generate a connection string that uses an oledb provider. A Sybase ODBC Connection String would look like this

```
"ODBC;Driver={SYBASE ASE ODBC Driver};Srvr=myServerName;Database=my_db;UID=myUsername;PWD=myPassword"
```

Alternativly, you could create an odbc DSN (using [ODBC data source adminitration](http://unitysolutions.com/Helps/Unity_ODBC/HTML/index.html?odbc_data_source_administration.htm)) and then use a connection string like this

```
"ODBC;DSN=my_DSN;UID=myUsername;PWD=myPassword;"
```

In case you are connecting through .net, why don't you install the native provider Sybase.Data.AseClient (Adaptive Server Enterprise Managed Provider). In that case the connection string would be like the following

```
Dim cn As New AseConnection("Data Source='servername';Port='5000';UID='myUsername';PWD='myPassword';Database='my_db';")
```

Comment: How to install Sybase.Data.AseClient (Adaptive Server Enterprise Managed Provider). For that I am not getting the direct link

Comment: It is included in the Sybase ASE installation cd (ASE Data Providers - ADO.NET)